# Same call on DLL twice, with pinvoke, getting different results

Tags: c#, fortran, pinvoke

I'm using a fortran DLL (compiled with mingw), of which I have no control of, on a C# application (net45, VS2013, windows 7 64), through Pinvoke. It, however, has the strange behavior of producing different results from absolutely equals calls. It's a little bit more complex than that, check the example (assume 'get' is the ddl method):

**First C# Run**

1. 'get' call produces '200'
2. 'get' call produces '-100'

**Second C# Run**

1. get call produces '200'
2. get call produces '-100'

The correct result is always the one of the 1st get run. I believe that there is some sort bad memory usage going on, as i actually have had a similar problem, where 'get' could not be called a second time (it would crash). Initially i tried loading the DLL's once for all calls, and then reloading before each, but both behave exactly the same. See them below:

**Loading the dll once for all calls**

```
[DllImport(@"gamma.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void get_(ref GammaInputStruct inputParams, ref int nobs, float[] utmx, float[] utmy, float[] dobi, float[] embi, float[] sobi, float[] tci, float[] gamma, float[] matrixOut);
```

**Reloading the dll before each call** (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/06/typesafe-getprocaddress.aspx)

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        delegate void GetDelegate(ref GammaInputStruct inputParams, ref int nobs, float[] utmx, float[] utmy, float[] dobi, float[] embi, float[] sobi, float[] tci, float[] gamma, float[] matrixOut);

using (var lib = new UnmanagedLibrary("gamma.dll"))
            {
                var func = lib.GetUnmanagedFunction<GetDelegate>("get_");
                func(ref input.InputParams, ref input.Nobs, input.Utmx, input.Utmy, input.Dobi, input.Embi, input.Sobi.ToArray(), input.Tci, input.Gamma, matrixOut);
            }
```

Finally, below is how the "gamma.dll" is compiled and also the source code of the method's signature.

**Fortran compilation:**

```
gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\  -ffree-line-length-none -ffixed-line-length-none -Wall -g -DBUILD_DLL -fPIC  -ffixed-form -ffree-form    -c "Gamma14.f90" -o obj\Debug\Gamma14.o
```

**Fortran get signature:**

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::get
      subroutine get(inputParams,nobsIn,utmx,utmy,dobi,embi,sobi,tci,gammaArray,matrixOut)
```

Last but not least, this code runs on a WPF GUI, with inputs chosen by the user, and so it can run an infinite number of times, with same, or different inputs.

I ran out of ideas. Got some?

Thanks!

**Update----------------**

Also tried copying (different name) and deleting the DLL between calls, no success.

My knowledge of DLL's/memory usage is very basic, but what I hope is for there to be a way to make each call a completely new one, which would make the code resistant to some fortran code smells. Trying and fixing the fortran code is not much of an option, given my time constraints.

**Update 2--------------**

I found more information on the problem, and managed to solve it. I was making two pinvoke calls on two distinct DLL's, both fortran, with different and unrelated source codes. They are part of a pipeline, but on the examples below the calls are completely unrelated to each other, for the sake of testing. Lets call them 'DLL1' and 'DLL2':

- Situation 1: Run 'DLL1' multiple times -> OK
- Situation 2: Run 'DLL2' multiple times -> OK
- Situation 3: Run 'DLL1' once, and then 'DLL2' multiple times ->
  **BAD**

See the answer below.

Comment: If you know both runs return 200 (or at least should), why are you calling it twice?

Comment: This code is used by a WPF GUI, and thus can run an infinite number of times, on the same, or different inputs. The inputs of the calls are chosen by the user.

Comment: The problem is most likely not on the C# side and you will have to look at the DLL you are using.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that like the plague, anyway it is probably not even possible, within my constraints. Maybe there is a way 'refresh' the DLL?

Comment: Can you try to call the dll method some 5+ times in a row to determine if it always change to the second value or produce a "static" sequence of some sort?

Comment: You are in denial. Stop hoping for a magic solution. You need to understand both sides of the interface.

Comment: Your suggestion is for me to understand it? Really? Whatever you mean by that, I'm going to take a guess and say I do understand it (I have the source code, can run it, and am the one who compiles the DLL, but again, the code was not made by me, though i have made some minor changes to be able to pinvoke it). Also, if you know that the solution for such a problem, without tampering with the fortran code, is magical, i take it you have some knowledge to spare. Why not do that instead of making such a useless, borderline insulting comment?

Comment: Oh, so you know what I need too. Well, let me correct you. What I need is for the program to work properly. I do not need to 'get to the bottom' of the issue, only enough to solve it and to have a reasonable guarantee that it will keep working in the foreseeable future. You see, this is how the real world operates, often times, for in reality, resources are limited. Do you actually have anything useful to add? Are you some sort of stackoverflow troll?

Comment: If you don't care about getting things right, and don't want to understand your program, then there's not much point in this conversation. Good luck.

Comment: You say that like you actually had anything remotely useful for the solution or even understanding of the program. But I agree with you, this conversation is beyond pointless. Have a nice day.

Comment: How could anyone help without any information? The answer is in the code you didn't show.

Comment: Do you expect me to post thousands of lines of fortran code here? I posted what I tought was relevant and readable (the method signature). There are ways of helping, it was just either beyond your will, or beyond your skills. If you are interested in helping I suggest you take a much less arrogant approach, and try asking for more information.

Comment: We did ask for more information. You said you didn't want to do that. Comments 3 and 4 above. You expressly said that you did not want to address the real problem but that you wanted a "refresh", what I then described as the magic solution. I'm surprised you can't see this. The problems are in the code that we cannot see. What you need to do is some debugging. Isolate and identify the problem. Obviously you don't post all of your code. You debug and isolate the problem. Usually once you've done that you can solve it yourself, but if not then you post a [mcve] and we help.

Comment: First, nobody asked for more information. Second, I did not say I would not do that. What comment thread are you reading? The "refresh", you so eagerly describe as magic, is a way to make each call completely new. I guess that means I'm a wizard, since I found a way to do it, good to know. Again you tell me what I need, will you delete your comment again? Even now all you do is give generic advice "isolate and identify the problem, do some debugging". Really? If you can't help answer a question within its constraints (real world, limited resources), don't. You have a toxic behavior.

Comment: You haven't found a solution. You also have not produced an answer that has value for future visitors. You don't get to decide what is a valid question here. This site has quite strict rules and this question falls outside of them. If there were more people in the pinvoke tag it would have been closed. Isolate and identify and debug is the best advice you can get. Nobody can give you concrete advice without you doing that first. There is no viable general purpose refresh. Beyond loading and unloading for each call. Is that what you did?

Comment: Again, you stick to your definition of solution. Check a dictionary for a proper definition. As it turns out, you don't get to decide what is an invalid question here, this site has strict rules for this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. This has value for future visitors, provided they have a similar issue. I for one would be happy to have found such a question/answer before I had to make mine. It just does not have value for you, learn the difference. If you have the time to completely understand every problem you have, good for you. Not everybody can have this privilege.

Comment: No I don't get to decide that. The community does. I do know what a solution is. I am confident that *"I still can't really understand the cause for all this, but anyway, this works"* is not a solution to any problem. And I'm even more sure that neither the question nor answer are valuable to others. Not least because only you know what any of this means. For instance, what does loaded dynamically mean? p/invokes are all loaded dynamically. Do you mean the DLLs are loaded and then unloaded, the unloading being the key.

Comment: As for what questions are valid here, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Your question falls squarely into the category laid out in list item 1. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Did you even bother to read the question? You keep asking me what is already explained, even when there is code available. I won't repeat the information here. Also, you are wrong again, I do not seek debugging help, that is just you, once again, 'knowing' what I need. For a proper definition of solution, see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/solve: "To find an answer to, explanation for, or way of dealing with (a problem, for example)." . I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic again, without your preconception in mind.

Comment: There is only half of the code. The issue lies in the code you didn't show, the Fortran, the code you've stated that you will not investigate. A solution requires a problem. We don't know what the problem is. Nor do you. You have stated that many times. Instead you've tried something (the details of which are far from clear) by trial and error and achieved something that seems to work. You are happy. Fine. That's up to you. I personally believe in doing jobs well, gaining understanding, and knowing for sure that I understand both problem and solution. You disagree. Which is fine.

Comment: The problem lies in the title, and in the description: "Same call on DLL twice, getting different results". What you are looking for is the root of the problem. Attacking the root of a problem is not always a possible approach. For example, in medicine, sometimes doctors can't attack the root cause, simply because it's unknown, or unviable. Sometimes this is good enough, sometimes it is not (like a returning disease). To classify a job as well done, you can't just look at end product of the job itself. You have to look at the constraints and conditions in which that job is inserted.

Comment: We just disagree on this. Let's leave it there.

Comment: Well, finally we agree on something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried reloading the 'DLL1' before each call and it worked. I did some more tests, and found that unless i do this for **both** of them, it won't work.

I still can't really understand the cause for all this, but anyway, this works.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically loaded"? All p/invoke calls load the DLLs dynamically. Is what you mean that you call `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` explicitly? And then `FreeLibrary` when the function call returns? In other words, each repeated function call results in a load, call, unload cycle.

Comment: Yeas i unload it with each call. Although this may seem like a heavy impact on performance, it is not, because the call takes around one minute to complete (regardless of how often I unload it).

Comment: It's not that you are dynamically loading. You cannot statically load a DLL for pinvoke, its all dynamic. It's that you reload and so reinitialize. Clearly there is some state in the DLL.

Comment: Ok, i will upload the info on both my question and answer.